# Using active cell value and address in formula VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to create a formula or a macro that invokes a formula that will grab the active cell's value and address and apply data validation for its current value.

As an example, if A1 held the value dog, then I would add a data validation formula as follows:

=ISNUMBER(FIND("dog", A1))

However, I want it to work for any cell generically like this:

=ISNUMBER(FIND(ActiveCellValue, ActiveCellAddress))

Here is my macro, but I don't know VBA so I can't get it to work:

```
Sub dataValidate()
'
' dataValidate Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+r
'
CellVal = Application.ActiveCell.Value
CellAdd = Application.ActiveCell.Address



With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=isnumber(find(CellVal,CellAdd))"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
End Sub
```

Anybody know how to get this to work?

Comment: A bit confused: isn't `=ISNUMBER(FIND(ActiveCellValue, ActiveCellAddress))` going to be always TRUE?

Comment: `"=isnumber(find(CellVal,CellAdd))"` - variables shouldn't fall within quotes. The normal approach is to concatenate them into the string with `&`.

Comment: ^^^^^ `Formula1:="=isnumber(find(""" & CellVal & """," & CellAdd & "))"`

Comment: @BigBen It would set which value is being "found" each time you ran the macro. If you run the macro and then try to change the value without running the macro again, it would still be looking for the value it was set to.

Comment: @ScottCraner 's solution is correct.

Comment: @Axfinger - sure, my point is that `=ISNUMBER(FIND(ActiveCellValue, ActiveCellAddress))` will always be true (initially) for the `ActiveCell`.

Comment: @BigBen Yes, the purpose of this is to setup up a particular cell as a template value that you don't want other people to change when using the sheet as a template.